# Local caching resultsets from a database in .NET 3.5 if I can't use SQL Server Caching

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, oracle, caching

I have a .NET application running in a production environment, which connects to an Oracle database back end.

For availability reasons, I need a local database cache. The current caching solution using DataSet does not perform very well (data loading from back end, storage as XML, local queries on the cache, multithreading issues with DataSet).

What alternatives are there, which are
a) fast
b) reliable
c) do not add a further level of complication doing the inevitable cache synchronization?

- I have thought about MS SQL Server Compact Edition as a local store, but have no experience with it.
- As an alternative I thought about SQLite, but the fact that it needs COM Interop seem to complicate things. The pure .NET reimplementation of SQLite seems to be abandoned.

Comment: what about SQL Express?

Comment: There is not much info here on what, how much you are caching.  If you need high availability, it may be better looking at how your db environment is architected?

Comment: Hi all, I was rather concerned about availability in terms of network outages or planned or unplanned database downtimes. The amount of data to be cached is medium sized, e.g. at most several thousand records.